# How do i change the Colour of the link on my Navbar when the correct page is loaded?

Tags: javascript, html, css

The problem is really bad and i need help. please help me as i am stuck and i have tried multiple things. so Please help me I really need help. This is for a website i am making in class. I have tried many things and none of them have worked!
i would prefer to do this in JQuery but i dont think i can. Can i do this or not?

```css
li {
  float: left;
}

.current-link {
  background-color: #4caf50;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
  background-color: rgb(77, 77, 77);
}

ul {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
#homeGreeting {
  text-align: center;
  color: #000100;
}

body {
  background-color: rgba(131, 122, 122, 0.479);
}
h1 {
  font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
}

#WelcomeIMG {
width: 60%;
height: auto;
text-align: center;
}

.center {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

#TOPNAV {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

#BOTTOMNAV {
  background-color: #000000;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.COPYRIGHT p {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Mamoth's Site - Home Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul id="TOPNAV" class="topnav">
      <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="Review.html">Review</a></li>
      <li><a href="Contact.html">Contact</a></li>
      <li style="float:right"><a href="About.html">About</a></li>
    </ul>
    <h1 id="homeGreeting">WELCOME TO MAMOTH'S WEBSITE!</h1>
    <br/>
    <image id="WelcomeIMG" src="Welcome.jpg" class="center"></image>
    <ul id="BOTTOMNAV" class="COPYRIGHT"><p>&copy;Brayden Kennedy-Wilcox 2019</p></ul>
  </body>
</html>







<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Mamoth's Site - Home Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul id="TOPNAV" class="topnav">
      <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="Review.html">Review</a></li>
      <li><a href="Contact.html">Contact</a></li>
      <li style="float:right"><a href="About.html">About</a></li>
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Mamoth's Site - Home Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul id="TOPNAV" class="topnav">
      <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="Review.html">Review</a></li>
      <li><a href="Contact.html">Contact</a></li>
      <li style="float:right"><a href="About.html">About</a></li>
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Mamoth's Site - Home Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul id="TOPNAV" class="topnav">
      <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="Review.html">Review</a></li>
      <li><a href="Contact.html">Contact</a></li>
      <li style="float:right"><a href="About.html">About</a></li>
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

`

Comment: You already have separate, static documents. What's keeping you from adding `class="active"` to the current navbar link and style it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Please use below jquery code. It will first take your web URL and check the is your URL in href than it will add class to your link.

  ```
  $(document).ready(function(){


  $('#TOPNAV a').each(function(){
  if(location.href.indexOf($(this).attr('href')) != -1){
    $(this).addClass('current-link');
  }
  });

  });
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Since each of your navigation items links to a new page, you can easily create a new CSS class.

You give it the color and set the class to the link element:

```css
.active {
  color: #f00;
  font-weight: bold; /*Wahtever you want to do... */
}
```

```html
<!-- index.html -->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Mamoth's Site - Home Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul id="TOPNAV" class="topnav">
      <li><a href="index.html" class="active">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="Review.html">Review</a></li>
      <li><a href="Contact.html">Contact</a></li>
      <li style="float:right"><a href="About.html">About</a></li>
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>


<!-- Review.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Mamoth's Site - Home Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul id="TOPNAV" class="topnav">
      <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="Review.html" class="active">Review</a></li>
      <li><a href="Contact.html">Contact</a></li>
      <li style="float:right"><a href="About.html">About</a></li>
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Manually add "active" class to "a" tags in navigation and use something similar in CSS

`#TOPNAV li a.active { color: red; }`